# On refreshing page redirect user to startpage - with rewrite rules iis

Tags: angularjs, iis, url-rewriting

The angularjs app will be initialized on the url http://ip.us/angularjs/

The angularjs generates urls like

http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/
http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/link

When the user hits the refresh button the iis should redirect thenm to 
http://ip.us/angularjs/

I created the following rule:

```
   <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="angularjs" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="#.*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://ip.us/angularjs/" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

But it seems that it will be ignored for example on http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/
Whats wrong with the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is only provided the URL before the hashtag. That's the reason it's used in AngularJS to provide client-side routing. When you hit http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/ the server only sees http://ip.us/angularjs/ . The "#/link/" is a "bookmark" for the browser to use (or in this case, AngularJS to use to decide what client-side route to match).

Therefore, your matching rule on IIS will never trigger. Check your server logs and you should see that the path info from the # sign on doesn't show up in the request. Of course, I believe the server side of your setup is doing exactly what you're wanting. It's always delivering http://ip.us/angularjs/ regardless of what might exist after the #.

So, the rewriting you're wanting to do needs to be handled client side in Angular -- though I'm not exactly sure what behavior you're wanting.

If you're wanting reloads to go somewhere else (i.e. always start at "#/"), consider checking a scope/rootScope variable (or abstracting it into a Service to make it cleaner) in one of your controllers (w/o knowing how your app is setup, I can't be more specific), and going to your base angular route if the value is null (since a reload would cause this value to be reset). Then you just set that value to true at your base route -- therefore forcing everyone to go through the base client side route after a reload.

Of course, understand that the default behavior is generally what people want. If someone is at http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/ and hits reload, the default behavior for an Angular app is that it will reload http://ip.us/angularjs/ from the server (which should be your Angular html with links to everything else it needs) and will match the "#/link/" route/state in your ngRoute or ui-router mapping.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. When I refresh the page on http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/ the exact same page will be loaded. I want the behaviour like you descriped. On a refresh of the page http://ip.us/angularjs/#/link/ the http://ip.us/angularjs/ should be loaded

Comment: just make sure it's clear to you that ip.us/angularjs/ is ALWAYS being loaded from the server on refresh, even if ip.us/angularjs/#/link is in the address bar. So, i think the behavior you're wanting is that when you hit reload ip.us/angularjs/#/link, you want it to client-side redirect in angular to ip.us/angularjs/#/ . Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok so the server ships always ip.us/angularjs/ but the angular core handle it that the user get the correct previous page which was open. So, yes, I want to achieve a redirect to ip.us/angularjs/#/ on refreshing the page.

Comment: Okay. So, yes, the description I gave above applies. You need to maintain state in some fashion, to distinguish between someone who arrived at #/link from #/ vs. someone who did a clean refresh. You can do this via scope/rootScope variable or a Service. Alternately, you could avoid using ngRoute/ui-router entirely, and just use ng-include instead to load partials w/o updating the URL. In that case, you would never have #/links in the address bar at all. The main reason for doing #/anything is to specifically allow deep linking and reloads, which is what you're trying to avoid.